# How to deploy nx monorepo applications with AWS Amplify

Tags: aws-amplify, nrwl-nx

Running into several problems while trying to deploy NextJS applications within my mono-repo to AWS Amplify-

1. Amplify has difficulty detecting that this is a NextJS application
2. Confusion on where to run build commands from / the location of dist

I found (limited) [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/monorepo-configuration.html) on creating an `amplify.yml` spec for a monorepo deployment on AWS Amplify. I'm not quite sure what I want to configure particular variables as, since I'm not sure what Amplify is doing under the hood when you deploy.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
version: 1
applications:
  - appRoot: ./apps/myNextJsApp                
    frontend:
      phases:
        preBuild:
          commands:
            - cd ../..
            - yarn install
        build:
          commands:
            - npx nx build myNextJsApp --prod
      artifacts:
        files:
            - dist/apps/myNextJsApp/.next
        discard-paths: yes
        baseDirectory: location
      cache:
        paths:
            - dist/apps/myNextJsApp/cache
    test:
      phases:
        preTest:
          commands:
            - *enter command*
        test:
          commands:
            - *enter command*
        postTest:
          commands:
            - *enter command*
      artifacts:
        files:
            - location
            - location
        configFilePath: *location*
        baseDirectory: *location*
```

My specific questions:

1. What is the proper appRoot? It would seem to me that it would be the `apps/myApp` directory, however I see some documentation within Nx that it should be just `./`.
2. Is `yarn install` my only necessary pre-build command? In that .yml I have it configured for starting in the `apps/myApp` directory and the cd'ing out to the root where my `yarn.lock` & `package.json` are located.
3. Is `npx nx build myApp --prod` sufficient?
4. Is this the correct location in my `amplify.yml` to specify my `.next` and `cache` directories?
5. What do `baseDirectory` and `discard-paths` do?

Thank you in advance to anyone who can help me demystify the `amplify.yml`.